# How do you change the environment variables for VLC on macOS High Sierra?

Tags: mac, high-sierra

Recently, I was working on a project when I cam upon the following instruction (one of the many here: https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app/wiki/Mac#3---install-dependencies) :

> After you've installed VLC, set the following environment variables:
>
> **VLC_PATH:** point this to the VLC libs folder.
>   *Sample Mac OS X location:* `/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib`
>
> **VLC_PLUGIN_PATH:** point this to the VLC plugins folder.
>   *Sample Mac OS X location:* `/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/plugins`

How does one do the following? I am using High Sierra, macOS. My Shell is ZSH.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score -1):

From the terminal

```
nano .profile
```

Then paste the following lines:

```
export VLC_PATH=/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib
export VLC_PLUGIN_PATH=/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/plugins
```

To save, press `Ctrl + X` then press `Y` and finally `Enter`. Afterwards, restart your terminal.

Comment: Keep in mind this isn't actually setting the environment variables VLC_PATH and VLC_PLUGIN_PATH as requested, but rather adds those two folders to the generic PATH.

Comment: Only edit .profile if you are using sh